# Upgrading Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS to Newer LTS Kernel

Tags: 14.04

We run ubuntu on AWS cloud and recently experienced multiple crashing issues with 2 servers that where running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with kernel 3.13.0-48-generic.  AWS recommended that we upgrade to to 16.04 to get the new 4.4 kernel version since they have seen other customers with crashing issues in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS under this kernel.

There is the linux-lts-xenial kernel in the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS repos named (linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic) and I was wondering if upgrading to this kernel version in 14.04 was following best practices for dealing with these types of crashing issues in Ubuntu Server or is it best practice to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS version?

Also, is there any risk with installing a backported kernel version from 16.04 in 14.04 as far as compatibility with particular versions of packages?

Comment: [This says the newer kernel is recommended for cloud/virtual usage.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Answer (score 1):

You can see on the attached image that the Kernel that is delivered with 14.04.5 is in fact the HWE Kernel of 16.04 and should be compatible/identical

[Ubuntu Kernel Support Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support)

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krz88.png)